# How to Decoupling customer services to controllers in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Guys:

I'm using dotnet-core-mvc to build a web site recently.
I've written a "pagedList" class and it includes a "paging" method.
It can work in my controller now, but I want to decoupling this class
with my controller, how should i do to make my "pagedList" class can
decoupling with my controllers?

Is it a good way to regist my "pagedList" class to /Startup.cs/ConfigureServices?
THX!

Here is my code:

/Services/PagedList.cs:

```
public class PagedList<T>: List<T>
    {
        public int TotalPages{get;private set;}
        public bool HasNextPage{get; private set;}
        public bool HasPrevPage{get; private set;}
        public int PageIndex{get; private set;}

        public PagedList()
        {           
        }

        public async Task<IQueryable<T>> Paging(IQueryable<T> collection, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            int count = await collection.CountAsync();
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count/(double)pageSize);

            if (pageIndex <= 0) { pageIndex = 1;}
            if (pageIndex > TotalPages) { pageIndex = TotalPages; }

            PageIndex = pageIndex;            
            HasNextPage =  (pageIndex < TotalPages) ? true : false;
            HasPrevPage =  (pageIndex > 1) ? true : false;

            collection =  collection.Skip(( pageIndex - 1 ) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            return collection;            
        }
    }
}
```

/Controllers/XXController.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ...

    PagedList<XX> pageList = new PagedList<XX>();
    data= await pageList.Paging(data, pageIndex, pageSize);
    ...

    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a demo worked,you can create a IPagedService and PagedService,and then register in the startup.cs.

User.cs:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

IPagedService.cs:

```
public interface IPagedService
    {
        PagedList<User> PagedList(); 
    }
```

PagedService.cs:

```
public class PagedService : IPagedService
    {
        public PagedList<User> PagedList()
        {
            return new PagedList<User>();
        }

}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IPagedService, PagedService>();
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPagedService _pagedService;
        public TestController(IPagedService pagedService) {
            _pagedService = pagedService;
        }
        public IActionResult Test() {
            PagedList<User> users = _pagedService.PagedList();
            return View();
        }
    }
```